# How to setup Trading view pine script alert notification for strategy.exit which is using stop, trail_points and trail_offset

Tags: pine-script

I created a script which is working flawlessly on Tradingview so I wanted to create alert notifications. Buy order is coming after certain conditions get satisfied and I'm creating an alter through alertcondition() function, as follows

```
//Buy Condition
Buy = condition1 and condition2 and testrange
alertcondition(Buy, title = "Buy Signal", message = "Buy Signal Alert")
```

I'm stuck in the sell order alert notification as I'm using strategy.exit() which has stop, trail_points and trail_offset. So the strategy either hits stop-loss or it starts trailing from a certain percentage with an offset.

```
//Exit Strategy 
strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Enter Long", stop=StopLoss * (1 - sl_inp), 
   trail_points = close * TrailPer / syminfo.mintick, 
   trail_offset = close * TrailOffset / syminfo.mintick)
```

**I  can't use alertfunction() here as the trailing stoploss and offset are both defined in strategy.exit function. 
So how can I set up an alert notification for the exit? Please help!**

Comment: Even though the code compiles, alerts don’t work with strategies.

Comment: @BarisYakut thanks for your reply. 

Absolutely, that's the reason I changed the buy order notification (strategy.entry) to Buy Condition and used alertcondition() as portrayed above. 

As I understand now that for the sell order notification I need to create manual code for stop, trail_points and trail_offset >> then create a condition with sell >> then use altercondition() to send the sell order alert.
    
I've been looking for trailing stoploss script online but can't find any which has stop, trail % and offset. Please help!

Comment: The [PineCoders Backtesting & Trading Engine](https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/) has code for fairly sophisticated stop logic.